# Why does my matplotlib pdf pagination context manager not work in python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've been writing the following context manager + iterator class to automatically make multipage pdfs with a specified number of axes per page, adding new pages as required.  It works fine under python3, but in python2 I end up with blank plots on all but the last page.  Any ideas?

```
from future.utils import implements_iterator
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages, FigureCanvasPdf
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


@implements_iterator
class PdfPaginator(object):
    def __init__(self, pdfpages, nrow, ncol, **kwargs):
        self.pdfpages = pdfpages
        self.nrow = nrow
        self.ncol = ncol
        self.naxes = nrow*ncol
        self.kwargs = kwargs

        self.i = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.i % self.naxes == 0:
            # If current fig exists, clean it up before creating a new fig
            if self.i != 0:
                self.pdfpages.savefig(self.fig)
            self.fig, self.axes = self.subplots(
                    self.nrow, self.ncol, **self.kwargs)
        self.i += 1
        return self.axes.ravel()[(self.i-1) % self.naxes]

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.pdfpages.savefig(self.fig)

    @staticmethod
    def subplots(nrow, ncol, **kwargs):
        fig = Figure(**kwargs)
        # Following line seems to be required, but I'm not sure why.
        FigureCanvasPdf(fig)
        axes = [[fig.add_subplot(nrow, ncol, i+ncol*j+1)
                 for i in range(ncol)]
                for j in range(nrow)]
        return fig, np.array(axes, dtype=object)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.random.normal(size=(50, 50))
    y = np.random.normal(size=(50, 50))

    with PdfPages("blah.pdf") as pdf:
        with PdfPaginator(pdf, 3, 4, figsize=(8.5, 11)) as p:
            for x_, y_, ax in zip(x, y, p):
                ax.plot(x_, y_)
```

Comment: `def __next__(self):` try add `def next(self):` which does the same (python 2 name). I'm not sure but it's something that isn't python 2 compatible in your code.

Comment: /questions/36212812/python-2-someiterator-next-vs-nextsomeiterator-python-3

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't think that's it.  Note the [@implements_iterator decorator for py2/py3 compatibility](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#custom-iterators), and the fact that the code runs fine in python 2, it just produces the wrong output.

Comment: oh, right! The main difference I'm seeing next is the heavy matplotlib package you're using, and which is different in python 2 and python 3. There may be a difference in version / bugs in the python 2 version.